# Showing certain levels in outlines in word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2011

In word, when we create an outline, is there a way to close lower levels from view. For instance, if the outline is

> [image]

Then how can we just show the levels represented by the roman numbers (I, II), hiding the levels represented by the uppercase letters (A, B, C) and the arabic numerals (1, 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How can I expand/collapse outlines in Word?

This is a new feature introduced in Word 2013.

> Word 2013 introduces a new feature that allows you to expand and
>   collapse certain parts of your document. It reminds me very much of
>   the kind of web page interactivity that lets you click on a brief
>   summary of something to display a more detailed description. And
>   that’s precisely what this is.

Source [Expand And Collapse In Word 2013](http://www.word-2013-tutorials.com/expand-and-collapse-in-word-2013/)

---

#### What if I have an older version of Word?

In older versions of Word there are addons that will do the same, for example 
[More Add-in](http://moreaddin.com/about/) (paid software):

> **Adds Expand and Collapse to Word Documents**
>
> With the More Word add-in installed, making part of a document expand-
>   and collapse-able is as easy as formatting text as Bold or Italic:
>
> Beyond creating and using simple collapsibles, More Add-in provides a
>   lot of support for the collapsible "power user" - for example,
>   automatic creation of collapsibles for all headings, or creating your
>   own custom toggle buttons.

There are also two VBA scripts at [Toggle Data Display](http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/toggle_data_display.html) which might be of interest:

> This Microsoft Word Help & Microsoft Word Tips page provides some methods and techniques to allow the document user to show/hide (or expand/collapse) document content.